# Question about SfM and camera re-localizatoin with ground truth camera pose

Tags: structure-from-motion

all!

I'm a beginner on computer vision field :)
I have 2 questions about SfM and camera re-localization.

As I know, the general pipeline of SfM can be summarized as follow,

```
1. Extract local feature
2. Match local features(key points) between image pairs
3. Triangulation the key points between image pairs for estimating 3D point
```

Next, the camera re-localization operated.
My questios are here

1. I'm currently researching about the effect of noised camera pose on SfM. But, I can not find when the GT camera pose input to above SfM pipeline. Aren't the 3D points estimated from triangulation real coordinate?
2. If the answer of above question is **NO**, how can the camera re-localization work then?

Thanks for all kind answers in advance :)

I tried to make SfM model with 7scenes, cambridge datasets.
But some sample SfM codes provided  public generate the SfM model with only the images.